# PDO Check if row exists

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a registration script written in PDO. When the user registers, the code below is supposed to check if the username already exists in the database.

- If it does, it displays an error.
- If it doesn't, it inserts the inputted data to the database.

**The issue is that even if the username exists, it still inserts the inputted data into the database.**

Here's my database connection:

```
$db_username = "username";
$db_password = "password";

$con = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database", $db_username, $db_password);
```

Here's my registration script:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$checkusername = $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username=':username'");
$stmt->bindParam(':username', $_POST['username']);
$stmt->execute();
if($checkusername->rowCount() > 0) {
echo "Username already exists.";
}else{

$status = 'Hello there!';
$about = 'Hello!';

$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, password, email, status, about) VALUES (:username, :password, :email, :status, :about)");

$stmt->bindParam(':username', $_POST['username']);
$stmt->bindParam(':password', md5($_POST['password']));
$stmt->bindParam(':email', $_POST['email']);
$stmt->bindParam(':status', $status);
$stmt->bindParam(':about', $about);
$stmt->execute();

header('Location: index.php');
}
}
?>

<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="username">
<input type="password" name="password">
<input type="email" name="email">
<?php echo $errorusername = !empty($errorusername) ? $errorusername : ''; ?>
<?php echo $errorpassword = !empty($errorpassword) ? $errorpassword : ''; ?>
<?php echo $erroremail = !empty($erroremail) ? $erroremail : ''; ?>
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: `WHERE username=':username'`  Remove the single quotes in the query

Comment: Thank you, that seems to of done the trick!